# Accessing file in apk through app

Tags: android, file, apk

I am pretty sure that this is possible, but would just like to check. 
I would like to know how to access a file that is within an apk. The file gets added to the apk when I build, but I am not sure how to specify the location of the file (relative path). I have given the relative path but that does not seem to work.

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: "The file gets added to the apk when I build" -- please be more specific about *where* in the APK this file "gets added".

Comment: I open the apk with 7zip and I can see the file there (root of apk i guess). I use maven to build.

Comment: The file is a certificate file I am trying to read.

Comment: Please store it in `assets/` in your project, then use Mr. Wasser's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is in your "assets" folder in the APK, then you can access it like this:

```
 InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("FILENAME");
```

where `FILENAME` is the file name including path **relative to the assets folder**

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to just get the path of the file as well?

Comment: @viper: There is no "path of the file". The file does not exist outside of your APK. It is inside your APK.